# Regexp for :name, :othername, :other

Tags: java, regex, language-agnostic

I'm trying to get all the names in a string like this:

```
:name, :lastName
```

But I don't seem to find a correct way.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
/^(:((\w+)(,:(\w+))+).*)$/
```

In Java:

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile("(:((\\w+)(,:(\\w+))+).*)");
Matcher m = a.matcher(":name,:lastName,:bd");
if( m.matches() ) { 
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m.groupCount() ; i++ ) { 
    out.println( i + " = " + m.group( i ) );
  }   
}
```

Output:

```
0 = :name,:lastName,:bd
1 = :name,:lastName,:bd
2 = name,:lastName,:bd
3 = name
4 = ,:bd
```

And I'm trying to get a variable number of groups containing `[name, lastName, bd]`

**EDIT**

BTW, I'm trying to get this for a more complex regex to match simple things like:

```
 insert into table values ( :a, :b, :c )

/insert\s+into\s+(\w+)\s+values\s+(\( HERE IS MY QUESTION \))/
```

Comment: @kaj: `name, lastName, bd`, and so on ( *or group(n) = name, group(n+1) = lastName, group(n+2) = bd, group(n+m)=etc* )

Comment: Just to clarify: the problem is that repeating matches (\\w+)+ only keep the latest match, which is why `lastName` seems to be ignored.  I did not know this before.

Comment: I guess you should use some standard regex to validate the first part of the query (the text part) and then use the method by @MarcoS or @Aku for the bits that start with the ":".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a requirement that you place the result in different groups? This will oterwise work:

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile(":([^,]+)");
Matcher m = a.matcher(":name,:lastName,:bd");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Edit: ... and you can use split if you want to get an array of results:

```
String data = ":name,:lastName,:bd";
String[] parts = data.replace(":", "").split(",", -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Comment: No, it not a requirement, I just need to grab them in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile(":(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = a.matcher("insert into table values ( :a, :b, :c )");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Opps.. yeap, sorry, I'm trying to put it in a more complex regexp  :P

Comment: @MarcoS:  There's no need to use the `find(int)` overload here; it's for special cases where you have to start the search somewhere other than the beginning of the string.  The no-arg `find()` method is guaranteed to return all possible, non-overlapping matches as long as the Matcher isn't reset between calls.

Comment: @Alan Moore: you're right! thanks! I've changed my code, and also used `m.group(1)` which returns the strings without `:`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile(":([^,]+)");
    Matcher m = a.matcher(":name,:lastName,:bd");
    while (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is hard. Why not just `split()` it?

```
String inputString = ":name,:lastName,:bd";

for (String s : inputString.split(",?:")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @Oscar I see. I only prefer to extract tough bits like this as groups and kill them individually rather than try to pile it all into a central mass of regex nightmare. It feels like a "God class".

Comment: Me too, but this worked perfectly: `Pattern.compile(":([^,\\s]+)");`